# Column "does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, excel, table

[image: Message of why I cannot upload Excel file to create list]

I cannot create a list on either the Page or SubSite for several Excel files. I am getting the same warning message telling me the same thing shown below (Column " does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.) then the URL.

Comment: someone has deleted the column. Check if the column exists in the list settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  I decided, based on the responses here, to copy the column headers out to NotePad. Sure enough, many of them had quotation marks around them, but it didn't display in Excel ¯_ (ツ)_/¯.  Might be because I consolidated several lists into one. In Notepad, I deleted the marks, then pasted the name back into Excel or in some cases, deleted the column header name and retyped it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure none of your columns have brackets, "()" in the column name.

I had the same problem and was able to create a list when I modified a column name that had brackets in it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue when trying to create a list from an excel sheet generated from an MS Form.   One of my questions had a hard return in it.  When I deleted that from the cell in excel (so it was just text), I was able to import the excel & create the list.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found that there were several CR (carriage returns) within some of column heading cells (as opposed to wrap text). After removing all of them, I was able to import/create a list from excel. (The CR mentioned is entered within the cell by holding "ALT" then "Enter". It doesn't appear to leave a character that I could find when copied to text.)

Answer (score 0):

The CR was the exact problem. If you create a multiple-line header by using the ALT+ENTER, then Excel keeps the text together by enclosing it in quotes "".
Once I removed all of the CR's, then the list was created just fine.